# How to clear a string upon regeneration?

Tags: python, string

I am very new to Python & Stack Overflow so apologies if I misjudge or misidentify the issue.

I have a programmed a password generator (code below) and I have made an input for how many passwords you'd like to generate and how many characters for each.

When filling out the credentials, I have realized that it works correctly for the amount of passwords and the characters, but it prints the same password. I think I understand that the issue is that it prints the 'passwords' string which was previously generated in the for loop above, but I am unaware on how to make it print a different string for each number of passwords requested.

Here is my code:

```
import random
import os

clear = ('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')

print("Welcome to Your Password Generator!")

passwords = ""

characters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789!@£$%&().,^"

number = input("> How many passwords do you wish to generate? ")
number = int(number)

pwlength = input("> How many characters should your password be? ")
pwlength = int(pwlength)

os.system(clear)

print("> Here are your generated passwords: \n ")

for pwamount in range(pwlength):
    passwords += random.choice(characters)
for characterlength in range(number):
    print(passwords)
```

I apologize if the title or details are not descriptive as I am new to all this as a whole, If anybody has questions please give a response and I will try to respond with as much details as I can!

Thank you!

Comment: You need a nested for loop. 

```for characterlength in range(number): (indent)
 for pwamount in range(pwlength): (indent)
  passwords += random.choice(characters) (lower indent)
 print(passwords)
 passwords = ""```

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop is only generating one password at a time. Try something along these lines:

```
for password_num in range(number):
    password = ""
    for pwamount in range(pwlength):
        password += random.choice(characters)
    print(password)
```

The difference is that you want to generate and print `number` passwords. For this reason, the code to execute and print should execute `number` times, and that should be your outer loop. Then, for each password, you need to generate a password of length `pwlength`, then print it.

Right now, your `passwords` variable is only a string, not a list of strings.

Comment: Thank you! This actually makes me feel quite silly as I originally had a first version of this project where I practically wrote the same thing, I just forgot to indent the print(password) haha. It's all a part of the improvement process I guess! Thank you very much for this and i'll make sure to keep similar things in mind in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Your loops are wrong.

Just check this out and try it

```
import random
import os

clear = ('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')

print("Welcome to Your Password Generator!")

characters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789!@£$%&().,^"

number = input("> How many passwords do you wish to generate? ")
number = int(number)

pwlength = input("> How many characters should your password be? ")
pwlength = int(pwlength)

os.system(clear)

print("> Here are your generated passwords: \n ")

for characterlength in range(number):
    print("".join(map(str, random.sample(characters,pwlength))))
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll make sure to try and dissect this myself and figure out what works where and why!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your code generates the password only once. I added an outer `for` loop to generate passwords corresponding to the `number`.

```py
import random
import os

clear = ('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')

print("Welcome to Your Password Generator!")

passwords = []

characters = list("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789!@£$%&().,^")

number = input("> How many passwords do you wish to generate? ")
number = int(number)

pwlength = input("> How many characters should your password be? ")
pwlength = int(pwlength)

os.system(clear)

print("> Here are your generated passwords: \n ")

for num_pw in range(number):
    password = ""
    for pwamount in range(pwlength):
        password += random.choice(characters)
    passwords.append(password)

for password in passwords:
    print(password)
```

Output:

```bash
Welcome to Your Password Generator!
> How many passwords do you wish to generate? 3
> How many characters should your password be? 5
> Here are your generated passwords: 
 
AqlY(
b!dHG
$Q1dk
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your problem is not setting the variable password to a blank string and then making a new password. I would strongly recommend using lists, in this case

```py
import random
import os

clear = ('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')

print("Welcome to Your Password Generator!")

passwords = ""

characters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789!@£$%&().,^"

number = input("> How many passwords do you wish to generate? ")
number = int(number)

pwlength = input("> How many characters should your password be? ")
pwlength = int(pwlength)

os.system(clear)

print("> Here are your generated passwords: \n ")
global pwlist
pwlist = []
for i in range(number):
  for pwamount in range(pwlength):
    passwords += random.choice(characters)
  pwlist.append(passwords)
  passwords = ""
for password in pwlist:
  print(password)
```

something like this should work

Comment: Thank you very much! Lists is a semi-new concept to me where I haven't had much practice so it's definitely something I need to look at learning and utilising!